# Complex virtual attributes creation/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So basically, my app contains users (model User) who have friends (unilateral access), and who also own lists.

What I'm trying to achieve here is when creating a new list, to provide it with "accessors", picked from the user's friends.

My code is heavily inspired from the following [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes) on virtual attributes.

So, here comes my User and UserAccessor model (just the relevant parts) :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end

class UserAccessor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accessor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :accessible_list, :class_name => "List"
end
```

My List model :

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :user_accessors, :foreign_key => "accessible_list_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :accessors, :class_name => "User", :through => :user_accessors

  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 1 }

  attr_writer :authorized_users
  after_save :add_accessors

  def authorized_users
    @authorized_users || self.accessors.map(&:username).join(' ')
  end

  private
    def add_accessors
      if @authorized_users
        accessors = @authorized_users.split(' ').map do |username|
          user = User.find_by_username(username)
          if user
            if self.user.inverse_friends.include? user
              self.user_accessors.build(:accessor_id => user.id).accessor
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

The form used to create or update the list is the following one :

```
= simple_form_for [@user, @list] do |f|
  = f.input :title, :label => "Titre"
  = f.input :authorized_users, :label => "Authorized users", :hint => "Separated by spaces"
  %p
  = f.button :submit
```

So my problem comes from the fact that I don't know exactly how to create/update the accessors, my code `self.user_accessors.build(:accessor_id => user.id).accessor` definitely not working to fill it correctly.

I'm still quite a noob in rails (and ruby in general…), so I hope what I put there was relevant enough for you to help me! Thanks in advance!